# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent select with

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Before I describe the problem here for a long time, short and sweet:
`Laravel 5.4`

In theory files should be returned with the corresponding name and ID of the user.

```
return Files::with(['user' => function($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'name');
  }])->select('filename', 'uid')->paginate();
```

However, the ID is missing in the query.

```
select `filename`, `uid` from `files` limit 15 offset 0
select `id`, `name` from `users` where `users`.`id` in ('')
```

The relations in the models are available

```
//User.php
public function files()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Files');
}
//Files.php
public function user()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why? After all, there is no way to pass the ID as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager loading can only work when the parent query selects the foreign key column:

```
return Files::with(['user' => function($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'name');
}])->select('filename', 'uid', 'user_id')->paginate();
                                ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer :D